# Bounce rates and very low conversion rates

Tags: e-commerce, conversion-rate, product-design

My site seems to be producing very high bounce rates (60% plus) and because of this the conversion rate suffers massively.

Here is a users journey:

They search for '80s fancy dress' in Google and enter the site through an Ad. They land on this page [costumecrowd.co.uk/80s-fancy-dress/](http://www.costumecrowd.co.uk/80s-fancy-dress/) scroll to the bottom, back to the top and then bounce.

Now I understand it's very possible they just dont see anything they want, but the range is quite large and other pages much larger.

So my questions is: What things could I try to lower bounce rates with the current product range? If I can get some direction I can go ahead and split test ideas, I just need some expert advice on problem solving this issue.

I have heard 'product reviews' play a massive factor so maybe this might help?

Comment: and also: http://blog.kissmetrics.com/c-o-n-v-e-r-t-s/

Answer (score 2):

I looked around the site and saw that you have a huge selection. Unfortunately, you only have one information hierarchy to help customers find a particular costume. A "Search" box will go a long way to helping people stay on the site searching for costumes.

In addition, another set of links at the bottom of the page might be helpful with options like "Maybe you would like to see "70's Fancy Dress. 90's Fancy Dress, Village People, etc."

Answer (score 1):

When you're into web analytics, you need to understand what you're measuring. Not only can it be wrong of you just focusing on convention rates, but also bad for business.

Why? You may rightfully ask. Conversion rate is one of many measurements you can do on a site, which is the number of wanted actions per visitor. Now is 10 percent good? One? One tenth? It doesn't say anything really. But you can use it as a relative figure on you site. Last month it was 0,015 percent and this month it is 0,019 percent. We increase from last month - good!

But your real issue here is whether or not you're making money or losing money. Convertion Rate doesn't tell you that, but your balance scorecard does. We had costs of 10000 and income of 9000. And at that rate our conversion rate was X and no of visitors Y meaning we had Z successful actions. We need to increase Z by 10 percent units to break even.

This is my advise, focus on the right figure. More to read: [Is Conversion Rate Enough? It's A Good Start, Now Do More!](http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/is-conversion-rate-enough-its-a-good-start-now-do-more/)

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, I understand what you are saying so ill have a good read of that link and also try to think about CR in the way you explain, hopefully ill be able to optimise better in the future your way.

Answer (score 0):

Probably targeting the wrong keywords in adgroup since you sell costumes not dresses.... *but... you're right, reviews play a huge roll... you'll also do better with badges, an EV certificate (SSL)... Your marketing (messaging + callouts + look & feel of the site) aren't very good... which has me guessing your AdWords add needs help too...  check out: [http://www.amazon.com/The-One-Sentence-Persuasion-Course-ebook/dp/B00AAF5GJK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AAF5GJK)

Comment: You also need to be mobile optimized...

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the constructive criticism. Could you expand on why those elements plus look and feel are not great? If you was working on this site what would trouble you the most?

Comment: Sure... for 1) I literally can't buy a product above the fold...The header takes up a ton of space ...I have to scroll down to see the first product. 2) "We have a great range of 80s Fancy Dress for everyone..." isn't very catching, effective, or enticing. 3) visually the color scheme is bland... 4) the font in your navigation is to thick of a weight to be in caps and white on blue... 5) Its too plain, you're selling whacky costumes, but the site doesn't match the product.

Comment: 5) your need help banner feels like a search input (because of placing, layout, and style... and it says need help ), I even clicked it a few times trying to search. 6) There is no call out... ON THE POSITIVE SIDE: The pink back drop and layout of the drop down menu's is decent.

Comment: Your biggest problem I still think is your targeting people looking for a classy dress not a costume.

Comment: The other thing you can do is install Zopim, and start talking to the people who hit that page and get their direct feedback.

Answer (score 0):

**"Bounce rate"** is one of the most often misapplied and misunderstood metrics.

What it is interpreted as is *"User did not engage with your content"*.
Fine, except that the *default* definition of a bounce is *"user did not navigate to another page on your siet".*
This definition is problematic.

So if user spends three minutes browsing all of your content on a page and does a full scroll then clearly they *are engaging* with your site by browsing for what they are looking for. This not the same as someone arriving on page and leaving without trying to achieve their goal because *"something feels off"*

So quite common is to configure analytics : if user > 10 seconds on page or scrolls the page then [fire an event](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033068#NonInteractionEvents) to prevent mis-leading bounce stats.  Obviously adjust rules for content on your site.

Now you have 2 groups: (1) those that engage with the listing and then exit and (2) those that don't engage with the page at all. That is 2 different problems. But at least you can focus accurately on the most priority problem.